# add values to a list from specific part of a text file

Tags: python

I am having this text

> /** Goodmorning
>
> Alex
>
> Dog
>
> House
>
> Red
>
> */
>
> /** Goodnight
>
> Maria
>
> Cat
>
> Office
>
> Green
>
> */

I would like to have **Alex , Dog , House and red** in one list and **Maria,Cat,office,green** in an other list.

I am having this code

```
    with open(filename) as f :
        for i in f:
            if i.startswith("/** Goodmorning"):
                #add files to list
            elif i.startswith("/** Goodnight"):

                #add files to other list
```

So, is there any way to write the script so it can understands that **Alex** belongs in the part of the text that has **Goodmorning**?

Comment: It'll be good if you'll accept one of answers you find best

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use `dict`, where "section name" will be a key:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    result = {}
    current_list = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("/**"):
            current_list = []
            result[line[3:].strip()] = current_list
        elif line != "*/":
            current_list.append(line.strip())
```

Result:

```
{'Goodmorning': ['Alex', 'Dog', 'House', 'Red'], 'Goodnight': ['Maria', 'Cat', 'Office', 'Green']}
```

---

To search which key one of values belongs you can use next code:

```
search_value = "Alex"
for key, values in result.items():
    if search_value in values:
        print(search_value, "belongs to", key)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). In python there is a module for this called [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re

s = """/** Goodmorning

Alex

Dog

House

Red

*/

/** Goodnight

Maria

Cat

Office

Green

*/"""

pattern = r'/\*\*([\w \n]+)\*/'
word_groups = re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)

d = {}
for word_group in word_groups:
    words = word_group.strip().split('\n\n')
    d[words[0]] = words[1:]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'Goodmorning': ['Alex', 'Dog', 'House', 'Red'], 'Goodnight': 
['Maria', 'Cat', 'Office', 'Green']}
```

Answer (score 1):

expanding on Olvin Roght (sorry can't comment - not enough reputation) I would keep a second dictionary for the reverse lookup

```
with open(filename) as f:
    key_to_list = {}
    name_to_key = {}
    current_list = None
    current_key = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("/**"):
            current_list = []
            current_key = line[3:].strip()
            key_to_list[current_key] = current_list
        elif line != "*/":
            current_name=line.strip()
            name_to_key[current_name]=current_key
            current_list.append(current_name)

print key_to_list
print name_to_key['Alex']
```

alternative is to convert the dictionary afterwards:

```
name_to_key = {n : k for k in key_to_list for n in key_to_list[k]}
```

(i.e if you want to go with the regex version from ashwani)
Limitation is that this only permits one membership per name.